# SSL - Internet Explorer issue empty cart on check out but works in firefox and chrome?

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, checkout

I'm running WP Ecommerce with Gold Cart in Genesis, my check out page doesn't work in Internet Explorer.  I have an SSL cert through bluehost.  Does anybody know of a way to fix this?  Is it an SSL issue?

Comment: What have you tested already? Is it working on other browsers?

Comment: Yes, it works on firefox and chrome.  I'm running wp ecommerce gold cart with genesis and news theme.

Comment: I have SSL on the check out page only.  The error comes from the product pages.

Comment: explorer 11 windows 7

Comment: Do you see any error message?